# Не хочет добавлять информацию в БД

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <? $db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'figures';
$db_username = 'root';



$connect_to_db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password)
or die("Не найдено соединение: " . mysql_error());


mysql_select_db($db_name, $connect_to_db)
or die("Не найдена бд: " . mysql_error());

?>
```

[image: Вот скрин бд]

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Документ без названия</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" action="add.php">

<input type="text" name="obj">
<input type="text" name="stl">
<input type="text" name="aboutStl">
<input type="text" name="aboutObj">
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Добавить"> 


</form>
<?
include('set.php');

if(isset($_POST['add']))
{       $obj = $_POST ['obj'];
       $stl = $_POST ['stl'];
    $aboutObj = $_POST ['aboutObj'];
    $aboutStl = $_POST ['aboutStl'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO figures(obj, stl, aboutObj, aboutStl) VALUES ('$obj','$stl,'$aboutObj','$aboutStl')"); 
    mysql_close;

}

?>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а дальше есть код?))) вроде как if  не закрыто } , да и form Не закрыта! ПРИВОДИТЕ полный код, из этой простыни пока видно как минимум две ошибки форматирования

Comment: Может быть </form> не закрыта?

Comment: А какую, собственно ошибку выдает?

Comment: @Денис там все ниже закрыто,просто вставил без лишних тегов

Comment: @Klym не выдает, просто не записывает в бд

Comment: @MichaelBocharov, а он вообще в эту ветку условия заходит? проверьте.

Comment: Попробуйте название ячеек в `ячейка`,

Comment: Магическая сила не хочет добавлять информацию в БД :)

Comment: Емм, а где подключение к базе?

Comment: @Vlad include('set.php');

Comment: @Khipster ну вот что не так то?

Comment: Представленный код выше весь находится в файле `add.php`? То есть action, по-сути, указывает на этот же файл? Добавьте в вопрос содержимое файла `set.php`. Если он большой, то можно под сниппет запихнуть.... + можно на http://sqlfiddle.com/  выложить dump своей таблицы и привести ссылку на sqlfiddle...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка в запросе, вы неправильно используете кавычки.

Попробуйте так:

```
mysql_query('
    INSERT INTO figures
    (`obj`, `stl`, `aboutObj`, `aboutStl`)
    VALUES
    ("' . $obj . '", "' . $stl . '", "' . $aboutObj . '", "' . $aboutStl . '")
');
```

Или так *(таким способом никогда не пользовался, но в теории должно тоже работать)*:

```
mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO figures
    (`obj`, `stl`, `aboutObj`, `aboutStl`)
    VALUES
    ('$obj', '$stl', '$aboutObj', '$aboutStl)
");
```

Для выяснения причин, попробуйте узнать что за ошибка:

```
$result = mysql_query('
    INSERT INTO figures
    (`obj`, `stl`, `aboutObj`, `aboutStl`)
    VALUES
    ("' . $obj . '", "' . $stl . '", "' . $aboutObj . '", "' . $aboutStl . '")
');
if (!$result) {
    die('Неверный запрос: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

И на скрине структуры БД у вас в двух последних столбцах, вроде бы, присутствует пробел - избавьтесь от него =)

**P.S.** У вас идеальный код для инъекции, используйте PDO и подготовленные запросы :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48777/discussion-on-answer-by-------).

Comment: @Николай Вы сами-то допустили ошибку, не заключив переменные в кавычки.... я исправил, но.....ох.....